# Using values in one list in a new list

Tags: list, netlogo

Sorry if this question have been asked before. The previous entries I think are related to my issue I just cannot seem to comprehend, terribly sorry for this.

I have created a list of 100 random numbers, and what I want is a second list with all the values of the first list divided by two.

```
set expectations_of_X n-values 100 [random 100]

set history-PV n-values 100 [expectations_of_X / 2]
```

When I run this I get the error of NetLogo expecting a number but got a list.

Answer (score 1):

I think I managed to solve it through help of earlier submissions

For anyone interested

```
set expectations_of_X n-values 100 [random 100]

let number 2

set history-PV map [[i] -> ( i / number) ] expectations_of_X
```

Very sorry for the trouble